# Remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY from current Activity

Tags: android

I have these activities:

A. products listing

B - product details (called with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

C - share product action

B is called from A, and B call others B activities recursively, it works fine here. But when I call C from B, I lost B returning to A, when I need is to keep B and return to it after leaving C.

Is there a way to remove the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY of B before calling C or maybe can you suggested me another approach?

Thanks.

Comment: I might not understand what you want to do, but it seems to me that you could simply removed the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY' when calling B and get the behavior you want.

Comment: B contains suggested products so if a client tap over one of them B is called again with the details of the product tapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what behavior you want.  As best as I understand, you want only one instance of activity B, and no history for earlier versions of activity B.  If so, you want to remove the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and instead call activity B with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and utilize `onNewIntent()` as described [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities).  Some might suggest you use `singleTask` or `singleInstance`, but be warned that those calls will destroy parts of the stack that it doesn't seem you want.

Comment: Yes I want only one instance of B and I found one solution removing FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY as you said before, then startActivity( B ) followed by finish()  give me the desired behavior, nevertheless I will try your suggestion. I will comment you later